# PermissionError when using python 3.3.4 and RotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am trying to get a rotating log file for a GUI application I am writing with python 3.3.4 and PyQt4.

I have the following snippet of code in my main script:

```
import logging
import resources

logger = logging.getLogger('main.test')

def main():
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    fh = RotatingFileHandler(resources.LOG_FILE_PATH, maxBytes=500, backupCount=5)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.info('main')
```

I have the maxBytes low so that I can test the rotating is working correctly, which it is not.  I am getting the following error whenever the log should be rotated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 73, in emit
self.doRollover()
File "C:\Python33\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 176, in doRollover
self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)
File "C:\Python33\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 116, in rotate
os.rename(source, dest)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\.logtest\\test.log.1'
```

And nothing is logged.  Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: @TLDr..be a good citizen and mark the answer that worked for you or answer your own question if you have a different solution

Answer (score 7):

In my case it happens only in Windows. To solve it I changed the **delay** parameter to True for my TimedRotatingFileHandler log handler.

Docs -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler

Answer (score 6):

Spent half a day on this as non previous answer resolved my issue.

My working solution is to use https://pypi.org/project/concurrent-log-handler/ instead of RotatingFileHandler. In multiple thread scenarios like Flask app, PermissionError will be raised when we rotate the log file that reaches maximum size.

Install `pypiwin32` to get rid of `No Module name win32con` error.

Thanks go to https://www.programmersought.com/article/43941158027/

Answer (score 5):

Instead of adding handler to the logger object you can directly specify handler in `basicConfig()`. If you add `RotatingFileHandler` to the logger object then one object might open the log file and another at the same time might try to rename it which throws the `PermissionError`.

Below code seems to work pretty well.

```
import logging
import resources
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', handlers=[RotatingFileHandler(filename=resources.LOG_FILE_PATH, maxBytes=500, backupCount=5)])
logger = logging.getLogger('main.test')

def main():
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.info('main')
```

Comment: this worked for me.  @TLDr..be a good citizen and mark the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify the same filename in both `basicConfig()` and `RotatingFileHandler()`. I had this same issue and I removed the filename parameter from `basicConfig()` and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Windows Server 2016 + IIS + FastCGI + Flask) finally I fix it by turning off files indexing in the folder.
[how-to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQl3q.png)

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22467917/9199668

Btw, it was working for months correctly... I have no idea why...

Answer (score 0):

Check that the file isn't being kept open by e.g. Windows file indexing, anti-virus or other software. Files that are open can't be renamed.

Comment: According to the error it is being used by the file that it is rolling to.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the application to use dictConfig and created a separate file that holds the dictionary configuration. At the top of my main application I have:

```
from log.logger import LOGGING

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
logger = logging.getLogger('testlogging')
```

Then in `log.logger` I have:

```
import logging
import sys
import resources

LOGGING = {
        "version":1,
        "handlers":{
                    "fileHandler":{
                        "class":"logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
                        "formatter":"myFormatter",
                        "filename":resources.LOG_FILE_PATH,
                        "maxBytes":100000,
                        "backupCount":5
                        },
                    "console":{
                        "class":"logging.StreamHandler",
                        "formatter":"myFormatter"
                        }
                    },        
        "loggers":{
            "aoconnect":{
                "handlers":["fileHandler", "console"],
                "level":"DEBUG",
                }
            },

        "formatters":{
            "myFormatter":{
                "format":"%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
                }
            }
        }
```

This all seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

In My case file size is full, after removing `server.log` file it worked

```
LOGS_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs')
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
    'log_file': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': os.path.join(LOGS_DIR, 'server.log'),
        'backupCount': 10, # keep at most 10 log files
        'maxBytes': 5*1024*1024 # 5242880 bytes (5MB)
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['log_file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'INFO',
        },
    },
}
```